# myCRED custom hook preferences doesn't update creds and log

Tags: plugins

I've created this plugin for myCRED to give some points when user publishes a post based on the number of attachments in the post. It's working but the problem is that I can't change the 'creds' and 'log' from myCred hook preferences! They won't update.

```
add_filter( 'mycred_setup_hooks', 'image_count_hook' );
function image_count_hook( $installed ) {
    $installed['images_count_hook'] = array(
        'title'       => 'images count for published posts',
        'description' => 'when user publishes a post, counts the number of images',
        'callback'    => array( 'images_in_post_hook' )
    );
    return $installed;
}
add_action('mycred_init', 'load_image_count_hook' );
function load_image_count_hook() {
    class images_in_post_hook extends myCRED_Hook {
    // Construct
    function __construct( $hook_prefs, $type = 'mycred_default' ) {
        parent::__construct( array(
            'id'       => 'number_of_images_in_post',
            'defaults' => array(
                'image_count' => array(
                    'creds'   => 70,
                    'log'     => '%plural% for images'
                ),
            )
        ), $hook_prefs, $type );
    }
    // Hook into WordPress
    public function run() {
        if ( $this->prefs['image_count']['creds'] != 0 )
            add_action( 'transition_post_status', array( $this, 'count_images_in_post' ), 30, 3 );
    }

    // Check if the user qualifies for points
    public function count_images_in_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
        $ID = $post->ID;
        $user_id = $post->post_author;
        $post_type = $post->post_type;

        // Check for exclusions
        if ( $this->core->exclude_user( $user_id ) === true ) return;

        // check if post is newly published
        if ( ! ($new_status == 'publish'  &&  $old_status != 'publish' && $old_status != 'private') ) return;
        if ( $post_type != 'post' ) return;
        // Make sure this is unique event
        if ( $this->core->has_entry( 'images_post_count', $post_id, $user_id ) ) return;

        $attachments = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID' ) );
        $total_attachments = count( $attachments );

        // Execute
        $this->core->add_creds(
            'images_post_count',
            $user_id,
            $this->prefs['image_count']['creds'] * $total_attachments,
            $this->prefs['image_count']['log'],
            $post_id,
            '',
            $this->mycred_type
        );
    }
        // Add Settings
    public function preferences() {
            // Our settings are available under $this->prefs
            $prefs = $this->prefs; ?>

    <label class="subheader" for="<?php echo $this->field_id( array('image_count' => 'creds') ); ?>"><?php echo $this->core->plural(); ?></label>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <div class="h2"><input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->field_name( array('image_count' => 'creds') ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->field_id( array('image_count' => 'creds') ); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->core->number( $prefs['image_count']['creds'] ); ?>" size="8" /></div>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <label class="subheader" for="<?php echo $this->field_id( array('image_count' => 'log') ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Log template', 'mycred' ); ?></label>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <div class="h2"><input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->field_name( array('image_count' => 'log') ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->field_id( array('image_count' => 'log') ); ?>" value="<?php echo $prefs['log']; ?>" class="long" /></div>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <?php }
    }
}
```

I can't find the problem. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meet same issue.
The id was problem.

In your case, **number_of_images_in_post** should be **images_count_hook**